# Database schema for multiple category of product with different attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, e-commerce, entity-attribute-value

I searched all over stackoverflow but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

This problem is related to an e-commerce website

**Here's the problem:**

A product from a specific category has a specific set of attributes. For example, a Computer has Ram, CPU, screen size ...etc
and a shirt has Size,Color ...Etc

There are attributes common to all products (e.g. price and stock etc.).

But how do I manage attributes specific to each product within its category?

At first I made a table for each category of a product where all the attributes are listed, but then I had a problem with filtering each product with its attributes. I'm sure that this is not a good idea because I have to create a new table when getting a new category. For example, if I wanted to sell books in my website I would need to add a books table

What way would be "best practice"?

Here's an example of what i did:

***product (idproduct, name,price,...(other attributes))

category (idcat,name,idParentCategory)

ParentCategory(idPcat)

PC(idPc,Ram,CPU,screenSize..etc)

Shirt(idShirt,size,Color)

Pants(idPant,waist,color)***

The problem here is that I cannot get a connection between the product table and its category in order to extract the propreties.

Is there a better solution ?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Follow the EAV tag for similar discussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are attributes common to all products (e.g. price and stock etc.).

Create a table for this with an appropriate real life key e.g. [EAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number) (consider using a third party data source for this).

> But how do I manage attributes specific to each product within its category? ... if I wanted to sell books in my website I would need to add a books table

Yes and the attributes specific to books would go here. Remember to create a reference to your 'attributes common to all products' table e.g. ensure the EAN correcponds to an valid [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number). Also consider that some book attributes might be common to other similar products, so you could have various subtypes modelled in your database.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve your problems, if i understood your issue well, is to map the attributes to the category table since they're category specific and not item specific.
This way, you'd have:
product(idproduct,name,price...(category attribute values))
category (idcat,name,idParentCategory,(category attributes))

And to map the products  to their category you'd just have a table with the two foreign PKs:
productOfCategory(idprodFK,idcatFK)

This would allow you to map products to the respective categories and validate the products' values to the categories' attributes.

Or you leave the array of values in the productOfCategory relationship.
For instance, for a product that is a computer, and therefore of the computer category, you'd have productOfCategory(ComputerProductID,ComputersCategoryID,"3.0‌​GHz,6GB Ram,.....")

Comment: what do you mean by adding catergory attribute balues in the product table ? can you please give me an exemple

Comment: You have two options, the way i see it.
Either you leave an array of values in the product entry, or you leave the array of  values in the productOfCategory relationship.
For instance, for a product that is a computer, and therefore of the computer category, you'd have
productOfCategory(ComputerProductID,ComputersCategoryID,"3.0GHz,6GB Ram,.....")

Comment: thank's for your help sir it was really useful to me

Comment: No problem mate. If you can give the upvote and mark as the answer, i'd be grateful

Comment: "array of values" - I don't think mySQL has proper support for such data structures.

Comment: @onedaywhen it doesn't. but in this case you can use a long varchar and then parse it at runtime. It's just the solution that came to mind

Comment: Well you could store a whole json object in there and deserialize it... but if you want to query the data using SQL then best to stick to the one data structure SQL understands i.e. atomic values in columns in tables :)

Comment: That is true, yes.
But it the number of tables for this case would be excessive imho. Different tables would need to be tailored for different categories, so you could map the products to them.